# How do I get the Haskell Platform's ghc-pkg to work on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I have installed the latest Haskell Platform for MAC OSX and I get the error "Setup: failed to parse output of 'ghc-pkg dump'" when I do anything with Cabal.

So I looked at my versions:

```
ralphtq$ ghc-pkg list Cabal
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/612/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.8.0.2
ralphtq-mac-mini:cabal-install-0.6.4 ralphtq$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.6.2
using version 1.6.0.3 of the Cabal library
```

This is telling me that even though I have Cabal 1.8 the cabal-instal is at version 0.6.2. I have tried to correct that using darcs to get the latest version of cabal-install, but I cannot get passed the error:

```
ralphtq$ sh bootstrap.sh 
Checking installed packages for ghc-6.12.1...
parsec is already installed and the version is ok.
network is already installed and the version is ok.
Cabal is already installed and the version is ok.
mtl is already installed and the version is ok.
HTTP is already installed and the version is ok.
zlib is already installed and the version is ok.
cleaning...
Linking Setup ...
Configuring cabal-install-0.9.1...
Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
Cabal ==1.9.*
```

It is expecting Cabal to be >= 1.9.

I tried to install a previous version of Cabal but got the following error:

```
...
...
[50 of 51] Compiling Distribution.Simple ( Distribution/Simple.hs, Distribution/Simple.o )
[51 of 51] Compiling Main             ( Setup.hs, Setup.o )
Linking Setup ...
Configuring Cabal-1.6.0.2...
Setup: failed to parse output of 'ghc-pkg dump'
```

I am back to the same problem.

I have also tried a complete re-install of the platform.

What are my next options? Help appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have installed an old version of the Haskell Platform, or you have a mixed up environment where you have installed over the top of an existing, older install, and so now have a mixture of ghc-pkg versions from 6.10.x and 6.12.x

Try removing those ghc-pkg and cabal binaries, and then installing the Platform. That way you won't have those old executables lying around.

Comment: Thanks Don - I will give that a try - be back in a few hours

Comment: Solution was simpler - installing Cabal-install-0.8.2 from Hackage - instead of using darcs - thanks